# Determinant of a Matrix recursively in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

I am trying to calculate the determinant of a Matrix recursevily.

The function I wrote does not take any parametres (because its a function in a class, so the matrix is defined by the "this->" command). 
So the minimum case I guess it is when a matrix 2x2 can be solved. In this case, in a matrix 3x3, it would be solved by multipling the 1st element with determinant of a 2x2 (2x2*3x3 - 2x3*3x2), but of course it has to do it recursevily... You cannot just write those values.

My code at the moment is this one:

```
int Matriz::calcularDeterminante()
{   
    int numero=0;
    int signo = 1;
    if (n_filas == 1) {
        return (this->matriz[0][0]);
    }
    else if (n_filas == 2) {
        return (this->matriz[0][0] * this->matriz[1][1]) - (this->matriz[0][1] * this->matriz[1][0]);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_filas; i++) {
            if (signo == 0) {
                numero += -1* matriz[0][i] * calcularDeterminante();
                signo++;
            }
            else if (signo == 1) {
                numero += signo * matriz[0][i] * calcularDeterminante();
                signo--;
            }               
        }
    }
return numero;
}
```

but the recursive call is just wrong.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to do the recursive call so it can solve the determinant

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show your code and explain what the problem is. Right now it sounds as if you were asking us to write the code for you

Comment: "the matrix is defined by the "this->" command" I dont understand what that means. Maybe adding some code (and a question) could make the question more clear

Comment: I'll edit the question with my code at the moment:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that whenever that code runs with a 3x3, you call calcularDeterminante() on the 3x3.

in the loop of your else statement, you should be creating the three 2x2 'sub' matrix and then call calcularDeterminante() on them. Personally I'd introduce a helper method that retrieves theses submatrix given a row,column.